# Azure LogicApp: how to use a repeater in a email body

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm starting to use `Azure LogicApp`. It is a good fun for easy workflow. I created a `HTTP` request to a webapi and in `Parse JSON` I have all data in `results` (in this example I have a list of movies).

I want to send an email and in the body I want to list the record (in the image I want to show `title` and `overview`). The procedure sends one email for each record (each movie in my case).

[image: Workflow]

Is there a way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your movies properties only have `title` and `overview` property, you could use `body('Parse_JSON')` as email body expression to get all the array json in a single email.

[image]

Otherwise, if you have more properties, you could use `select` action to choose the components in those JSON objects. And includes the outputs from the `actionBody('Select')` expression in the email's body:

[image]

For more details about how to use `select` action, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action).